# Table, Row valued UDFs in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

SQL Server (and some other databases) support a [`Table-value function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions). Is there a such thing as a Row-valued function -- where based on a set of input values, a specific row would be returned, or is that type of function type not supported. If not, why isn't it supported?

The example SQL Server gives is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ProductsCostingMoreThan(@cost money)  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN  
    SELECT ProductID, UnitPrice  
    FROM Products  
    WHERE UnitPrice > @cost
```

So a Row valued function might look like (I suppose):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCalculatedRow(@pk)
RETURNS ROW
AS
RETURN
    SELECT * FROM Products
    WHERE id=@pk
```

Maybe it makes no sense (as it'd be easy to have different row-shapes), but I was just curious if this type of thing is supported? I suppose it's the equivalent of a correlated subquery, so perhaps it might be useful (or at least convenient).

Comment: Quick answer: No. Why? Ok, why we need a function to return just one row, while we already have one which can return 1 or more rows.

Comment: @Ilyes -- I suppose a convenience around a correlated subquery which only allows one row? Or can a table function do that anyways?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249, the table function can return 0, 1, or more rows, whatever the query inside it returns. You can write your query `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM Products WHERE id=@pk` to guarantee that it will return no more than 1 row (it can still return 0 rows). Using such function in a broader query may be not very efficient. Do you have some specific problem to solve, or just a general curiosity? The current table-valued function is more generic than a "row-valued function", so it is hard to justify the need to have this feature.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov just a general curiosity -- if that is a 'thing' or it's always handled by a table-valued function (or something else).

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "row-valued" functions. You have scalar functions that return exactly one value or table-valued functions that return a table with a well-defined schema and any number of rows (0 or more). You can also use [correlated] subqueries and/or lateral joins (`CROSS / OUTER APPLY` in SQL Server) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of functions in SQL Server:

- Scalar functions that return a single value (i.e. "scalar")
- Table valued functions that return multiple rows or multiple values.

What you are describing is simply a variant of table-valued functions that return exactly one row (or perhaps no rows, which is possible in your example).

You can call such a function as:

```
select . . .
from t outer apply
     dbo.rowfunc( . . . )
```

Or:

```
select *
from t left join
     dbo.rowfunc ( . . . )
     on 1=1
```

Or:

```
select *
from db.rowfunc( . . . )
```

The first two return values even when no row is returned.  The third doesn't have that possibility (easily).

Note that some databases support "tuples" which is (I am guessing) what you mean by "row" -- multiple columns in a single "scalar" value.  SQL Server is not one of them.

However, you can emulate tuples using JSON or XML, if you want to return multiple values.

Comment: thanks for this. A couple questions: what's an example of a DBMS that supports a `tuple` ? What does the `outer apply` do?

Comment: Postgres is an example of a database that supports tuples.  `outer apply` implements a lateral join, which is a lot like a correlated subquery that can return multiple columns and multiple rows.

Comment: thanks, is there a link for the tuple in Postgres? I was googling a bit and it wasn't coming up as a type.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 . . . Postgres calls them "row constructors" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).  However, you need to see how they are used with comparisons operations and `in`.  Postgres also has composite types, so row constructors are like "anonymous" composite types.